# Translating a nested if statement into a set analysis expression

Tags: qlikview

I'm trying to translate this nested if statement into set analysis expression.

```
=Sum(if(Project=96,WorkTime*39.273,if(Project=92 and WorkType<>65,WorkTime*32.426,WorkTime*42.251)))
```

This is what I've done

```
=Sum({$<Project={96}>}WorkTime*39.273) or Sum({$<Project = {96}, WorkType -={65}>} WorkTime*32.426) or Sum({$<Project = {96}>} WorkTime*42.251)
```

I get an error near `WorkType -= {65}`, the problem is the operator. I've tried it even with <>, still an error.

Comment: How are you planning to use the set analysis statement? Your IF statement will work just fine for charts. BTW the `-=` operator is highlighted as an error in the editor, however, it works just fine (just a quirk of the editor).

Comment: Basically, i have two more expressions like this one, in one pivot table. Since each expression has its own filters, when applied they affect the other expression values. Thats why im trying to use Set Analysis, to ignore other filters.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to ignore some filters you can use your if expression combined with set analysis to ignore those fields like:

```
=Sum({<Field1_to_ignore = , Field2_to_ignore = >}if(Project=96,WorkTime*39.273,if(Project=92 and WorkType<>65,WorkTime*32.426,WorkTime*42.251)))
```